# An adjective for a deal/agreement that is withdrawn by one side?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

> The nuclear agreement is now a ----- deal. Trump *one-sidedly* withdrew it.

I want an adjective that shows a deal is withdrawn only by one side with no shortcoming on the part of the other side.

I thought about "betrayed deal". Is that idiomatic enough? Any other/better suggestions?

As an answer suggests, we can say "that is a broken deal". But "broken deal" says nothing about being "unilateral". I am looking for an adjective that implies that the deal is "unilaterally broken".

Answer (score 2):

Betrayal is quite personal: you can betray your country, a friend, or a promise, but you can't really betray an agreement or [deal](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=betrayed%20agreement&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=), because they are impersonal, like business transactions.

You can [break](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/break) an agreement, and you can talk about a [broken agreement](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=broken%20agreement&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbroken%20agreement%3B%2Cc0).

Note that the word [unilaterally](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unilaterally) is rather more elegant than one-sidedly.

You would not use the word break/broken if the deal were terminated by mutual consent. If you want to make it completely clear that the deal was broken unilaterally and you know who did it, it would be better to use a verb rather than an adjective.

> Trump broke the nuclear agreement

Usage of a verb opens up another possibility- the word [renege](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/renege), which carries quite negative overtones and makes the action sound a lot more dishonourable. it's messy to use as an adjective because it requires the preposition **on**.

> Trump reneged on the nuclear agreement

Comment: You could also use "unilaterally-broken deal," as in, "The nuclear agreement is now a unilaterally-broken deal."

Comment: Breaking an agreement is not the same as tearing it up. You can break your agreement with your mobile provider or bank, for example, but it doesn't imply that the agreement has come to an end. There is *repudiate*, but that is too technical for most situations. Otherwise you can just say *unilaterally terminated* or *withdrew the US from*.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to say someone "broke" a contractual obligation.  By default, you would assume the subject is the only one who broke the deal, unless you specifically say otherwise.

> Both sides accuse each other of **breaking** their agreement ...

The difference is in how *negatively* you want to portray this action.  To "break" an agreement is relatively severe, as it is a violation of trust.  If you want to be less severe you can say something like

> Trump **cancelled** the deal
>
> Trump **revoked** the deal
>
> Trump **nullified** the deal
>
> Trump **abrogated** the deal

all of which imply that the deal was written in such a way that one side could cancel it, at anytime, and without cause.  I don't know the language of the deal, so I can't say if this would be a fair statement ... but then again, in world politics, sometimes the actual language of a treaty is moot, and all that matters is which side has more power.  Classic example:

> [I am **altering** the deal, pray I don't **alter** it any further.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsW9MlYu31g)

In the other direction:

> Trump **tore up** the deal
>
> Trump **threw out** the deal (or, informally, "Trump **trashed** the deal")

suggests not only unilateral action, but strong personal feelings against the deal.

Another colorful alternative, used primarily *before* a deal is signed and/or ratified:

> Trump **torpedoed** the deal

This particular use is relevant to the Brexit situation, which has seen many potential deals *forwarded* and then *sunk* as unacceptable to one side or the other:

> [Labour MPs to urge Jeremy Corbyn not to 'torpedo' Brexit deal](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2019/apr/18/labour-mps-urge-jeremy-corbyn-not-torpedo-brexit-deal-second-referendum)